# Curious case of type of 2 in haskell

Tags: haskell

What is the rationale behind assigning a general type `Num a => a` to `2` instead of defaulting to some specific type like `Int` or `Integer`?

Secondly I have read at many places that `2` is a polymorphic value but the definition of polymorphism doesn't admit constrained variables. So is `2` polymorphic in Haskell?

Comment: To downvoter: care to explain what about this question is not to your liking? I'd say this is an interesting and non-obvious question. Please comment if you think the question is in some way not well posed.

Comment: `2` is a function, exactly like `(+)` or `(*)` only nullary. Why does `(*)` have the type it has? `2` uses the same reason. Is `(+)` polymorphic? So is `2`.

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Polymorphism

Comment: @n.m. I don't think it helps to reach for the concept of a "nullary function" to justify that. If `2  :: Num a => a` is a nullary function, so is `"foo" :: String`.

Comment: @duplode yes, "foo" is a nullary function, why is it strange or unusual? If you don't like it, use different terminoogy i.e. call (+) a variable (which it is). The bottom line, 2 is no different from (+) in this regard.

Comment: @n.m. I find it strange because it is much simpler to say that, in Haskell, a function is something with the type constructor `->` in its type. Calling Haskell non-functions nullary functions, while not unreasonable, is an extrinsic interpretation that doesn't really clarify anything (e.g. you might just as easily have said "they are all values, and values can be polymorphic"). For a more detailed formulation of this argument, see http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell

Comment: Haskell functions are functions in the mathematical sense, something a "nullary function" is not.

Answer (score 4):

`2` is polymorphic so you can use it as whatever type of number you like. The `Num` type class has a function `fromInteger`, which is used here. So `2` is really `fromInteger (2 :: Integer)`. If `2` was not polymorphic you would always have to write this if you wanted a non-Integer number, because there is no automatic coercion in Haskell (i.e. you can't do `(1 :: Integer) + (1 :: Int)`). The is the case for `Fractional` with `fromRational` by the way.

Polymorphic type variables can have constraints. If they do not have constraints, it is called *parametric polymorphism* and if they do *constrained*, *bounded parametric* or *ad-hoc polymorphism*. See also the [HaskellWiki article on polymorphism](https://wiki.haskell.org/Polymorphism).

Be aware, that you should not rely on type inference for your top-level functions or else you may fall trap to the [*monomorphism restriction*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction). For example if you write this at the top-level of a module:

```
polymorphic = 42
```

You may expect `polymorphic` to be of type `Num a => a`, but in reality Haskell will default the type of `polymorphic` to `Integer`.

Comment: I would also add that if you don't specify type of `2` explicitly and type inference doesn't assign concrete type to `2` constant then some monomorphisation take place: https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction

Comment: I'm not sure that the Haskell wiki is correct though. Typeclss introduces _bounded parametric polymorphism_, which is slightly different than _ad hoc polymorphism_. But I might be a bit pedantic here.

Comment: @Nicolas AFAICT they are not different.

Comment: @n.m. In general, ad-hoc polymorphism is a bit broader, it also includes overloading for example. In a Haskell context, there is no difference though.